# Change the Looks of a Website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, fast-search

Goal:
A new user and graphical interface that shall replace the SP2013:s templete.

Problem:
Is it possible to archieve the goal and still keeping Fast search's functionality? I prefer a customized looks of a website. I also want to change objec's position in different location in the page for instance the textbox for search field can be located on the right side.

In this context, I don't prefer the user and graphical  interface below. The picture was found randomly on Internet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most pages in SharePoint, the search page is made up of web parts and zones.  You can move web parts around into different zones or create a new page layout with zones where you want them.  You can also use CSS to customise further as needed.

So yes, you can achieve a very different interface without losing functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your help! My next question is. Where do I find these webpart and zone?     How important is it as a SP developer to have skills in webdevelopment (css, html, jquery)?

Comment: Edit the page like any other webpart page and you will see the zones. The zones are part of the default search result page layout. You may create and deploy custom layouts if you want.. All in a days work using for example SharePoint Designer.

Comment: CSS and HTML are pretty essential for SP Dev work.  jQuery is not exactly essential but it certainly significantly increases what you can achieve and gives you more options about how you get there.